# Thoughts on this Visitor

Tags: design-patterns

A typical Visitor basically dispatches a Visitor based on its type starting at the accept(Object).

Imagine a Visitor which works on Collection interfaces.

```
enum Visiting {
   STOP
   CONTINUE;
}

Visitor {
   accept( Object );
   Visiting visit( Object );
   Visiting visit( Map );
   Visiting visit( List );
   Visiting visit( Set );
   Visiting visit( Collection );
   Visiting visit( ArrayList).
}
```

An >ArrayList< in a typical Visitor would only call visit(List). Are there any advantages to call visit(Object) -> visit(Collection) -> visit(List) -> visit(ArrayList). If any visit 
returns Visiting.STOP the next inthe chain is not called ?

What possible arguments would make this a poor choice ?

- (-)performance rather than simply calling one visit based on type a whole chain happens.
- (+)easy to centralise common operations based on some super type without repeating.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The point of the visitor pattern is that the subclass instance decides which `visit()` method to call based on its own type. So, in this case, if ArrayList had an `accept(Visitor)` method (but it hasn't one), it would call `visit(ArrayList)`. The `accept()` method is in the visited object, not in the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

> If any visit returns Visiting.STOP the next inthe chain is not called
>   ?

Try Chain of Responsiblity instead of Visitor. 
You are using Visitor in wrong way, please refer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern